# Deferencing double pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to write a compare function for qsort and is having trouble with de-referencing double pointers.

I defined a structure

```
typedef struct {
    float x;
    float y;
} point;
```

and I made an array of pointers to point:

```
point* ptarr[2]={pt1,pt3} //pt1 and pt3 have type point*
```

My compare function is defined as follows:

```
int compare(const void * a, const void * b){
    return *(point**)a->x-*(point**)b->x;  //This is wrong
}
```

Since a and b are pointers to the values in the arrays, in my case they are pointers to pointers which point to struct point. Therefore I cast them into double pointer (point**), and then de-referenced it once, and tried to access the values inside struct. Compiler gave me a "request for member 'x' in something not a structure or union" error

I'm really confused about this. Can someone help me with it? thanks

Comment: `point* ptarr[2]={pt1,pt3}` - how did this even compile?

Comment: `point* ptarr[2]={pt1,pt3} //pt1 and pt3 have type point` Does that actually work ?

Comment: Sorry i made a typo. pt1 and pt3 are actually point*

Comment: When in doubt, add parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check a reference table on [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) you will see that the `->` access operator has higher priority than typecasting. This means that the expression `(point**)a->x` actually typecasts the `x` member not the `a` structure pointer. You want e.g. `(*(point**)a)->x`.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a syntax problem, really.

```
return *(point**)a->x-*(point**)b->x;        // This is wrong

return (*(point**)a)->x - (*(point**)b)->x;  // This is right
```

The reason you get an error because `*x->y` is the same as `*(x->y)`, but you want `(*x)->y`.

Also you have a bug in your code:

```
point* ptarr[2]={pt1,pt3} // pt1 and pt3 have type point
```

Do you see the bug?  Either `pt1` and `pt3` should have type `point *` (in which case the comment is wrong), or `pt1` and `pt3` should be replaced by `&pt1` and `&pt3`.  Errors in the comments should be treated as bugs, so it is a bug either way.